# Github Copilot in SAP Business Application Studio (BAS)

Tags: github-copilot, theia, sap-business-application-studio

has anyone tried to set up Github Copilot in BAS? I cannot find it inside of the extensions list and the Github Copilot documentation nowhere mentions BAS/ Eclipse. As far as I understand BAS is based on Eclipse Theia and it has a VSCode look and feel.

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to run Github Copilot in BAS?

Comment: To my understanding, this is not a technical, but a legal issue: [GitHub Copilot is provided only via the Visual Studio Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot), but [not via the Open VSX Registry](https://open-vsx.org/?search=copilot&category=&sortBy=relevance&sortOrder=desc) which is used by Eclipse Theia: [_"The terms of use for the Marketplace prevent any non-Visual Studio products from accessing it."_](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2020/march/1.php). Maybe installation work via file (_Download Extension_ in Marketplace).

Comment: Have you considered to ask this question ChatGPT? ;)

Comment: @howlger , I just did and it gave me a pretty long answer that went smth like this: ...Github Copilot is currently only available as an extension for Visual Studio Code.
...Install the VS Code extension for BAS: BAS is built ..
...Connect BAS to Github Copilot:
Open the Command Palette in BAS...
Search for "Preferences: Open User Settings" and select it
Scroll down to the "Extensions" section and select "Business Application Studio"
Scroll down to the "BAS > Advanced" section and add the following setting:
"bas.useVsCodeExtensions": true
Save the settings file and restart BAS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After keeping an eye out for some time regarding this issue I noticed that SAP has recently release a SAP BAS Studio Toolkit plugin- https://blogs.sap.com/2023/04/28/access-sap-business-application-studio-as-a-remote-from-visual-studio-code/

With this you are able to run BAS in your VSCode where you also can run Github Copilot.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the newly released VS Code extension "[SAP Business Application Studio toolkit](https://blogs.sap.com/2023/04/28/access-sap-business-application-studio-as-a-remote-from-visual-studio-code)" to expose SAP BAS to GitHub Copilot. Just install it in the ssh-forwarded container once you are connected to your dev space in Cloud Foundry.